# Adding Link Text to Animated D3 Tree

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, tree, data-visualization

**PROBLEM:** Link text is not rendering.

**GOAL:** To add link text to each path in a manner that 1) allows text wrapping and 2) ensures that text will transition in and out as nodes are selected/deselected.

**ORIGINAL SOURCE:** Located at: http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/raw/ed80661daf8e5fa89b85/

Every relationship/link has a descriptive predicate that can be seen in the data...

```
  var linkSet = [
    {source: "N0", predicate: "Predicate 1", target: "N1"},
    {source: "N1", predicate: "Predicate 2", target: "N2"},
    {source: "N2", predicate: "Predicate 3", target: "N3"},
    {source: "N0", predicate: "Predicate 4", target: "N4"},
    {source: "N4", predicate: "Predicate 5", target: "N5"},
    {source: "N0", predicate: "Predicate 6", target: "N6"},
    {source: "N6", predicate: "Predicate 7", target: "N7"},
    {source: "N6", predicate: "Predicate 8", target: "N8"},
    {source: "N7", predicate: "Predicate 9", target: "N9"},
    {source: "N7", predicate: "Predicate 10", target: "N10"}
  ];
```

I try an apply that predicate to each path, via a foreignObject with the intent that I'll be able to wrap predicate text, just like node text is wrapped.  The foreignObject is appended to the "path" element.  The code I use look as follows...

```
// Add Predicate text to each link path
link.append("svg:foreignObject")
    .data(linkSet)
    .attr("width", "200")
    .attr("height", "40")
  .append("xhtml:body")
    .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
    .html(function(d){ return "<p>" + d.predicate + "</p>"; });
```

However, while the DOM Tree shows that the foreignObject and the html "p" element are added and exist the text does not render.

Comment: What element do you have as the parent of the `<foreignObject>` element.

Comment: I append the foreignObject to the path element.

Comment: And that's your problem, `foreignObject>` elements cannot be children of path elements. You probably want them to be siblings.

Comment: Why is it that a foreignObject can be appended to nodes but not to link paths?  Also, does your answer imply that link/relationship text has to be drawn on the SVG canvas separately and transitioned in and out, separately, like nodes and links?

Comment: Nodes are `<g>` elements I think and they can have `<foreignObject>` children. I've no idea what your second sentence means so I'm going to guess the answer is no as I certainly didn't imply something I don't understand ;-)

Comment: Can a <g> element be appended to a <path>?  If I just append the <g> elements to the svg canvas (with foreignObjects appended), related text shows up in areas that are nowhere near the path links that they should be associated with.  I'd prefer to find a way to append the <g> and then the <foreignObject> to the path for each link.  If you look at the updated example, you can see the Predicate text show up, all jumbled together, in the upper left hand corner of the body (just above the "Relationship Density Control" text.

Comment: No, paths are basically leaf elements, they can only have non-visual children like `<animate>` and `<title>` elements.

Comment: Thanks again.  You've been very helpful.  Do you happen to know where I can go to read about what elements can or cannot be appended to each other (such as in the case of a <path> being a leaf) and why?  It seems like very useful information that I'm missing.

Comment: The SVG specification has a content model for each element. Here's path: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathElement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to add `<g>` elements to the SVG at the centroid of each path and then append `<foreignObject>` elements to each `<g>` element...

```
var linkTextItems = vis.selectAll("g.linkText")
    .data(tree.links(nodes), function(d) { return d.target.id; })

var linkTextEnter = linkTextItems.enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "linkText")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (d.target.y + 20) + "," + (getCenterX(d)) + ")"; });

// Add Predicate text to each link path
linkTextEnter.append("svg:foreignObject")
    .attr("width", "120")
    .attr("height", "40")
  .append("xhtml:body")
    .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
    .html(function(d){ return "<p>" + (linksByIdHash[d.source.id + ":" + d.target.id].predicate) + "</p>"; });
```